# Nginx reverse proxy setup issues with Docker containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, node.js, nginx

I have two running docker containers:

1. A Docker container running Nginx that serves Angular app resource files that were copied into the Docker image on docker build
2. A Docker container that is an api that is current listening on port 5007 internally on the container and 5007 externally on the host machine

I am setting up a staging environment and the following external urls:

- app.staging.mysite.com
- account.staging.mysite.com

app.staging.mysite.com hits port 80 and responds with the Angular app resources no problem.

Now I want to get *account.staging.mysite.com* external API URL request to hit my API Docker container listening on port 5007. Requests from *account.staging.mysite.com* will hit port 80 of the host machine.

Nginx will receive the *account.staging.mysite.com* port 80 requests and proxy them to Docker container *127.0.0.1:5007* while at the same time still serve my Angular app file by default for all external urls/ domains that I do not explicitly express for proxy in my Nginx config.

Instead of serving my Angular app I would like to use Nginx to forward the request to port 5007 so the my Account API can response. So I have altered my Nginx config to the following:

```
upstream accountstaging{
    server 0.0.0.0:5007
}
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;

    # Main
    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /index.html;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name account.staging.mysite.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://accountstaging;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
}
```

The thing that really surprises me is now there is no default_server hits. In other words, *app.staging.mysite.com*, which was working and responding with my Angular app resources is no longer working when I added the second server listening on port 80 specifically for *account.staging.mysite.com*.

So really this question is not that much about Docker containers, this is really about Nginx configuration. Though I am not entirely sure that my Docker containers could be excluded from being part of the problem. So here is my docker-compose.yml for *account.staging.mysite.com*:

```
version: '3'

services:
  apistaging:
    build: 
      context: ./
      dockerfile: docker/staging/Dockerfile
    image: tsl.api.account.image
    container_name: tsl.api.account.container
    ports:
      - "5007:5007"
    environment: 
      ASPNETCORE_URLS: http://+:5007
```

And here is my docker-compose.yml for app.staging.mysite.com:

```
version: '3'

services:
  frontend:
    build: 
      context: ./
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
    image: tsl.web.frontend.image
    container_name: tsl.web.frontend.container
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

Here is my Docker file for Nginx that serves my Angular app and is hopefully going to act as a reverse proxy as well, you can see that Nginx default_server servers my Angular app resource files that I copied into this Docker image on docker build:

```
FROM centos:7
MAINTAINER Brian Ogden

# Not currently being used but may come in handy
ARG ENVIRONMENT
ENV NODE_VERSION 6.11.1

RUN yum -y update && \
    yum clean all && \
    yum -y install http://nginx.org/packages/centos/7/noarch/RPMS/nginx-release-centos-7-0.el7.ngx.noarch.rpm \
    yum -y makecache && \
    yum -y install nginx-1.12.0 wget

# Cleanup some default NGINX configuration files we don’t need
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

#############################################
# NodeJs Install
#############################################

#Download NodeJs package
RUN wget -q -O - https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.gz \
    | tar --strip-components=1 -xzf - -C /usr/local

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/35774741/1258525
# use changes to package.json to force Docker not to use the cache
# when we change our application's nodejs dependencies:
COPY ./package.json /tmp/package.json
RUN cd /tmp && npm install
RUN mkdir /app && cp -a /tmp/node_modules /app/

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

RUN npm run build-$ENVIRONMENT

RUN cd /app && cp -a dist/* /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./docker/conf/frontend.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/frontend.conf
COPY ./docker/conf/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf     

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx"]
```

Is this issue possibly because of 80:80 binding for the Angular app frontend docker container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to this [question and answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46264954/connection-refused-while-connecting-to-upstream-when-using-nginx-as-reverse-prox), I was able realize that I had two issues going on:

1. the containers have different default Docker networks because I am using two different docker-compose.yml files, I had envisioned my Ngnix proxy working independently from any of my API containers entirely, including the docker-compose, more on that issue below
2. the second issue is simply when I tried to proxy to 127.0.0.1:5023 that is localhost inside the Ngnix container, not the network outside of the Nginx proxy container

So the different default networks being created by docker-compose for my Nginx proxy docker container and my api docker container are because I am using two different docker-compose.yml files. This is because I have Jenkins builds for many API microservices so the have independent docker-compose files and I needed a Nginx proxy to forward requests on port 80 to each microservice.

To test this out, created a docker-compose.yml for both containers, the API and the Nginx proxy:

```
version: '3'

services:
  reverseproxy:
    build: 
      context: ./
      dockerfile: docker/nginxproxy/docker/Dockerfile
    image: tsl.devops.reverseproxy.image
    container_name: tsl.devops.reverseproxy.container
    ports:
      - "80:80"
  apistaging:
    build: 
      context: ./
      dockerfile: docker/staging/Dockerfile
    image: tsl.api.example.image
    container_name: tsl.api.example.container
    ports:
      - "5023:5023"
    environment: 
      ASPNETCORE_URLS: http://+:5023
```

Yes there was still an issue, the proxy pass to http//:127.0.0.1:5023, that forward remains in the Nginx Docker container and never finds the API running on the Docker host, I simply needed to use the docker-compose.yml service name to get to it:

```
upstream accountstaging {
    server apistaging:5023;
}

server {

    listen 80;
    server_name account.staging.mysite.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://accountstaging;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
}
```